# One page site, dynamic content from database (as blog) - how to change URLs to page names

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink, content-management-system, permalinks

I suspect the answer is easy to find but I can't work out what question to ask so even that would be a great help.  I sort of need permalinks but my pages are not blog posts.

I have created a simple content management system.  All 300+ pages are accessed as page.php?page=34 and so on.  I would prefer to have those pages appear with individual page file names in the browser (banana.php etc.).  I did include a page name field in the database and wondered if there is a clever way to have that page name used.

The only way I can think to do it is to write some PHP code to amend .htaccess as any new page is created or deleted.  Wouldn't be hard but doesn't feel right for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way of doing this. You can simply just test if file exists on the URL in htaccess and if not rewrite everything into index.php and then parse the URL from inside the CMS. This is relevant part of .htaccess code taken from TYPO3 CMS, which solves this problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Sounds hopeful but I have no idea what you are saying;-)  Is there any documentation for that anywhere?

Comment: It basically says following: If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php with all the query parameters. For more documentation, I would suggest looking up each line in apache docs: http://www.askapache.info//2.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond